# ¿Cómo pasar un valor de un jTextField a otro si se cumple una condición de tamaño?

Tags: java, jtextfield

Alguien podría ayudarme a aprender como pasar un valor de un campo `jTextField` a otro campo igual si se cumple una condición?

Detallo mas el caso, tengo un `jTextField` llamado `txtcode`, lo tengo limitado a 9 caracteres como tamaño máximo, lo que quiero es crear una condición y es que cuando en ese campo se escriban 9 caracteres que es su tamaño máximo, me envié su contenido al otro `jTextField` llamado `txttitulo`.

Código del `jTextField` `txtcode` con la acción `keyTyped` para limitar su tamaño.

```
private void txtcodeKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                 
        int limite = 9;
       if(txtcode.getText().length()>=limite){

           evt.consume();

       }

    }
```

Comment: que error te marca el netbeans con .length()

Comment: Ya he solucionado el error, olvide borrar la parte donde lo menciono, lo solucione añadiendo el .length()>=limite){ lo que ahora tengo que aprender como pasar el valor si cumple la condición, ahora edito el post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba de la siguiente forma para pasar el valor si cumple la condicion.

```
jTextField2.setText(jTextField1.getText().toString());
```

Eso debe de ir dentro de una sentencia if.

De esta forma le indicas que el textfield 2 se le envia el valor del textfield 1 y automaticamente en tu formulario se visualizara la accion.

Comment: Estupendo me ha servido muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Tengo el mismo inconveniente pero el problema que al pasarlo al otro `JTextfield` que también tiene limite de caracteres el cual es mayor , no me permite ingresarle mas caracteres de los que tiene el anterior . es decir :

```
JTextfield1 = caracteres tiene 8

JTextfield2= caracteres tiene 10
```

Al momento de  `jTextField2.setText(jTextField1.getText().toString());` realizar algo así por el estilo me pasa el `JTextField1` al `JTextField2`, pero si le voy añadir las otras dos letras no me lo permite o solo me deja agregar una ...

Como puedo corregir eso ?

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow! Esta sección es expresamente para respuestas. Si este post no resolvió tu duda, lo recomendable sería formular una nueva pregunta con respecto al problema que tengas.